# Class files extracted in Equinox OSGi bundle cache?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp, equinox

I have an RCP application built of multiple custom plug-ins.

For several of the lower-level (but not lowest-level) plug-ins, **all the *class* files are extracted** from the plug-in jar into the OSGi bundle cache under the org.eclipse.osgi folder in the osgi.configuration.area.

The first launch using that configuration area is slow. Subsequent launches are fast. I don't know whether to blame this caching for the former, or credit it for the latter.

**QUESTIONS**

- Can I control whether a plug-in's classes are extracted into the cache?
- Do I want to?

**DETAILS**

This is not happening for most of the plug-ins. Size doesn't appear to matter. It's not the lowest-level plug-ins. It's not the set of plug-ins that contain Bundle-NativeCode.

Comment: Using `FileLocator.toFileURL` can cause the extract to happen.

Comment: @greg-449 - At first glance, that looks consistent with the plug-ins whose classes are being cached. I'll look into that later this afternoon. Thank you for the clue. I would never have found that.

Comment: @greg-449 - That looks like it was the issue. If you'd care to add an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a plug-in uses the FileLocator.toFileURL API this may unpack the code. The Javadoc says:

> The contents of the URL may be extracted into a cache on the
>   file-system in order to get a file URL.

You can sometimes avoid calling `toFileURL` by just using the `URL.openStream` method to read the resource without unpacking. APIs such as the JFace `ImageDescriptor.createFromURL` also don't require the file URL.

Answer (score 2):

Bundle jar files are stored there. If the bundle's manifest has `Eclipse-BundleShape: dir`, Equinox will honor that by unziping the jar into the directory.

The first launch after installing/updating/uninstalling bundles can be slower than subsequent launches since Equinox must run the resolver to compute package resolution for the bundles. This is cached to make subsequent launches faster.

Comment: Good to know. Doesn't seem to be the cause in my case. Thank you for the information, regardless.